# CSRF in Mautic - Invalid CSRF Token Error

Tags: mautic, csrf-token

I get this error every time I try to do anything in Mautic, e.g. Save a form, change password, etc. I have just migrated and updated Mautic into a new environment, based on the official mautic/mautic image from Dockerhub. I also changed the domain name.

Correct error message:

`CSRF token error. Try to refresh the page and try again.`

Here are some things I've tried to fix this:

1. Clear cache
2. Change username and password of the admin user, clear cache
3. Added `session.save_path = /var/php_sessions/` to php.ini, clear cache
4. Delete browser cookies, clear cache
5. `php app/console mautic:update:find`
6. `php app/console mautic:update:apply`
7. `php app/console doctrine:migration:status`
8. `php app/console doctrine:migration:migrate`
9. `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`
10. `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --env=prod --force`
11. `php app/console cache:clear` * 1000 times
12. Checked `mymautic.com/s/sysinfo` for error messages(fixed all errors)
13. Checked folder permissions, all green in the *Folder & File Permissions* tab
14. Delete cache directory

Yes, kind of some tricks ol' Google tipped me about. Now I'm out of ideas.
Or maybe 2 ideas left, because I changed the domain name, the CSRF-token is not happy :( how do I fix?

Or, Because I'm using Nginx as a loadbalancer so that the CSRF token gets lost on the way(But I was using the same setup before ).

Been trying to solve this for like 5 hours now, going mad. Gonna take a break from that now and hopefully some fellow stackoverflower has some nice brainstorming ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my error. After migrating I accidentally overwrote the new `media/js/app.js`  with the old one. ‍♂️